# Get same cells content into different different cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need help please to Get same cells content into different cells.

I have numbers in cells A1 - B1 - C1 - D1 - E1 - F1. 
I want to get those values respectively into the following cells:
H1 - I1 - J1 - K1 - L1 - M1.

I want these values to stay in these cells and whenever I update cells A1 to F1 I want to get their values into H2 to M2

[image]

Them whenever I update A1 to F1 again get their values to H3 to M3 and so on.
Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

I am not sure if this explanation is better. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `worksheet_change`?

Comment: How will you be updating A1:F1 ?  What would be the exact point at which those values should be copied to a row beow?

Comment: This site is not intended for wholescale code requests. It is meant to be used for specific Questions & Answers. If you attempt this yourself and run into issues, please ask a new question which outlines the problems that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim goout As Boolean

    goout = False
    xrow = 1
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:F1")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        xcolumn = Range(Target.Address).column
        Do
            If Cells(xrow, xcolumn + 7).Value = "" Then
                Cells(xrow, xcolumn + 7).Value = Cells(1, xcolumn).Value
                goout = True
            Else
                xrow = xrow + 1
           End If
       Loop Until goout = True
    End If
End Sub
```

copy this to sheet you want the event to take place in

Comment: Lance,

Thank you so much for your help. It works great for me. I tried to work on it by myself using the following Macro:

Sub Macro1()
erow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(erow, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
End Sub
but it keep updating the same row without switching to another row.

Thank you again and have a wonderful week.